# OpenERP OTRS Integration

Tags: integration, odoo, otrs

I am trying to integrate OTRS with OpenERP but I don't have any ideas to integrate. With the help of web service i want get all users records from otrs.If you have any ideas related this please share with us.
Software Specification:
OpenERP 6.1, OTRS otrs-3.1.10, MySQL 14.14, and Apache2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solve, with the help of otrs soap api, we can synchronize data of openerp and otrs.

Here we need to use all method of otrs which present in the this location:
/opt/otrs/kernel/system/...

Once we have create connection between us with root login id and root password with localhost. i can proceed to next steps, which we want to perform.

As i have to need to create connector which can maintain all ticket messaging in openerp as OTRS.

:)

Answer (score 1):

You're not too specific in what you want to achieve from the integration. In the case you need to import data into OpenERP, the [`import_odbc` module](http://openerpmanagementsystem.blogspot.pt/2012/09/import-odbc-modules-steps-up.html) can help you integrate data from MySQL into OpenERP. For webservices integration, you can find an example in the standard module `import_sugarcrm`.

UPDATE (2017-04-21):

Derived from `import_odbc` we now have [base_external_dbsource](https://github.com/OCA/server-tools/tree/10.0/base_external_dbsource), a pluggable base connector, to provide direct access to other systems. Plugins available include MySQL, Firebird and SQLite.

Comment: Just now, I want to creating and receiving customer information from OTRS through python code.

Comment: Personally, I'm using `import_odbc` to populate OpenERP `partner` table with data from an ERP database. It seems to me you can also use that strategy, you need to figure out the sql sentences to get the data you need out of MySQL.

Comment: ok, it the one way that we can access all records, but if i want to use web service to achieve all users information then how will be implement as otrs rest api or python lib or others.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now i am working properly with openerp and otrs with the help of otrs soap api...